# How to stop sumbitting a form in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms, async-await

I first get response of json object using fetch API. Then I'd like to check whether json.exist == true. If true, I wish the form to stop smbitting and print out the error message. However, it seems sumbits everytime when json.exist == true. How could I solve it?

```
  document.indexform.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  messages =[]
  user = {"username" : "123"}
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
  };

  const response = await fetch("/username",options)
  const json = await response.json()

  if(json.exist == true){
    messages.push("Username already exists")
  }

  if(messages.length > 0){
    e.preventDefault()
    errorElement.innerHTML = messages.join(',')
  }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

I would try a different approach.

Put

`e.preventDefault()`

at the top of your function, then submit the form using javascript if your conditions are met

```
if (json.exist !== true){
    document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
```